# Как остановить поток и весь скрипт по Ctrl-C на python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Сделал многопоточность и теперь ctrl+c не останавливает скрипт, только закрытие окна.

Пример:

```
import threading

def scan(): 
    for line in f:
        try:  
            do_something  
        except SomeError:
            pass
thread_scan1 = threading.Thread(target=scan, name='s1')  
thread_scan2 = threading.Thread(target=scan, name='s2')  
thread_scan3 = threading.Thread(target=scan, name='s3')  
thread_scan4 = threading.Thread(target=scan, name='s4')  
thread_scan5 = threading.Thread(target=scan, name='s5')  

thread_scan1.start()  
thread_scan2.start()  
thread_scan3.start()  
thread_scan4.start()  
thread_scan5.start()  

thread_scan1.join()  
thread_scan2.join()  
thread_scan3.join()  
thread_scan4.join()  
thread_scan5.join()
```

Как его завершить?

Comment: Thread(..., daemon=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
def scan():  
    try:  
        do_something  
    except KeyBoardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        pass
```

Возможно неверно, но идея в том, что нужно обработать исключение вызываемое Ctrl+C - KeyBoardInterrupt.

Comment: @andreymal это ничего не должно останавливать: KeyboardInterrupt в основном потоке выбрасывается и sys.exit в фоновом потоке в любом случае не помог бы. Чтобы остановить процесс,  можно os.exit (грубо) или кооперативно event.set() вызвать и проверять его в других потоках периодически.

Comment: @andreymal обратите внимание что scan только в фоновых потоках здесь вызывается

Comment: @jfs да, имел неосторожность не обратить)